# How to rotate each square of a pattern in fragment shader?

Tags: graphics, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I have a code that produces a simple grid using glsl. I'd like to rotate the squares 45 degrees to make them diamond shapes. Here's the code:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform vec2 u_resolution;

void main() {
    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution;
    vec3 color = vec3(0.0);

    st *= 3.0;      // Scale up the space by 3
    st = fract(st); // Wrap around 1.0
    color = vec3(st,0.0);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color,1.0);
}
```

I tried rotating the coordinates 45 degrees by adding the code bellow but it didn't work:

```
    vec2 rotated_st = vec2(st.x - 0.5, st.y - 0.5);
    rotated_st = vec2(rotated_st.x - rotated_st.y, rotated_st.x + rotated_st.y);
    rotated_st *= sqrt(2.0) / 2.0;
    rotated_st += vec2(0.5);
```

Comment: It would be nice if you (1) show what exactly draws the first code; (2) what the full updated looks like; (3) explain how you came to these formulas and why do you think they should work; (4) show what the updated code draws. This would help us to help you. Feel free to send me the project to my email "my first name dot, my second name at google.com" so that I can run and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about how you added the second code you shown to the first one but I did it like this and it worked :

```
void main()
{
    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution;
    vec3 color = vec3(0.0);

    st *= 3.0;      // Scale up the space by 3

    vec2 rotated_st = vec2(st.x - 0.5, st.y - 0.5);
    rotated_st = vec2(rotated_st.x - rotated_st.y, rotated_st.x + rotated_st.y);
    rotated_st *= sqrt(2.0) / 2.0;
    rotated_st += vec2(0.5);

    rotated_st = fract(rotated_st); // Wrap around 1.0
    color = vec3(rotated_st,0.0);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color,1.0);
}
```